# Python virtual environment in NX monorepo

Tags: python, node.js, nx-monorepo

I am using NX monorepo for one of my large javascript projects and one part of it relies on an external project that creates its own python virtual environment. Parts of my nodejs code are executing python commands and then retrieve the data required for the rest of JS build process.

In order to run NX scripts or tests, that virtualenv needs to be turned on, but the problem is that NX spawns its own processes that are isolated from the rest of operating system.

If I try to add NPM script that starts virtualenv `conda activate testenv` with `nx:run-script`

```
    "virtualenv-conda": {
      "executor": "nx:run-script",
      "options": {
          "script": "venv-conda"
      }
    }
```

or set it with `nx:run-commands` with

```
    "virtualenv-conda": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
        "commands": [
          "conda activate testenv"
        ],
        "parallel": false
      }
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
```

I am using ZSH on MacOS.

My questions are:

1. How do I start python virtual environment before specific tests?
2. How do I set up custom environment that will be used in these spawned processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest solution that I could find was to set env variable that leads to virtual envoronment's `bin` folder (on nix systems) or `Scripts` on Windows, and then prefix all commands with that specific path.

In short, just an idea if anyone else needs to develop their own solutions

```js
import { execSync } from 'child_process'

const pythonPath = '/absolute/path/to/specific/python/venv/bin'

const pyCmd = 'some_python_command'

execSync(pythonPath + ' ' + pyCmd, { stdio: 'pipe' })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Nx python plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nxlv/python), you can use the [`@nxlv/python:run-commands`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nxlv/python#user-content-run-commands-same-as-nxrun-commands) executor.

If not, you have 2 options:

1. Manually activate the virtual environment in your terminal before running the commands.
2. Use `nx:run-commands` executor and for each command add `source ./.venv/bin/activate ; your command`

The Nx `nx:run-commands` executor runs each command in a different process which is why you need to activate the virtual environment for each command you are running.

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I will try that and report back!